# HighChart showing future Time on X-axis for real time chart

Tags: highcharts

The below jsfiddle works properly functionally, but where the new ticks are added is too close to the Y Axis, so wondering if there is a way to show next two/three/10 intervals (whatever unit, seconds, minutes ...) in future on the X-Axis and the Y axis remains at the current time only (as usual)

Its like using the navigator, a user can go back, so using the navigator pane, the user can browse forward in time and can see some events that are marked as X-Axis plot band that would take place?

I this will make the chart more useful for the user and the current time and tick will be lot more visible.

Is it possible in HighCHarts?

http://jsfiddle.net/amonga141/6u8q9kgp/1/

```
    // Some styling options for yAxis
Highcharts.theme = {
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: "rgb(240, 240, 240)",
        minorGridLineColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07)',
        lineColor: "rgb(241, 141, 5)",
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickColor: "rgb(241, 141, 5)",
        tickWidth: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
            format: '{value:.5f}',
            style: {
                color: 'rgb(102, 102, 102)',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        title: {
            style: {
                color: 'rgb(229, 64, 40)',
                font: "bold 12px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
            }
        }
    }
};

// Apply the styling options
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

// Data generator helper
function data(start, end, samples, min, max) {
    var temp = [];
    var range = ~~ ((end - start) / samples);
    for (var i = 1; i < samples; i++) {
        temp.push([start.getTime() + range * i, min + Math.random() * (max - min)]);
    }
    return temp;
}

// 
var tooltipSuffix ='<br> TTIP Sufix:Suffix';
// Create a timer
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(now - 60000);

var example_data = [{
    name: 'Signal 1',
    data: data(start, now, 20, 1.55478, 1.55481),
    yAxis: 0
}, {
    name: "Signal 2",
    data: data(start, now, 20, 1.32419,  1.13253),
    yAxis: 1
}, {
    name: "Signal 3",
    data: data(start, now, 20, 0.97456, 0.97545),
    yAxis: 2
}];

//////////////////////
// Chart definition //
//////////////////////
var chart = $("#chart").highcharts({
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    chart: {
        animation: Highcharts.svg,
        events: {
            load: function () {
                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var chart = this,
                    series = chart.series;

                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = new Date(); // current time

                    series[0].addPoint(data(x, x, 2, 1.55678, 1.59133)[0], false, true);
                    series[1].addPoint(data(x, x, 2, 1.33456, 1.39921)[0], false, true);
                    series[2].addPoint(data(x, x, 2, 0.95989, 0.99092)[0], false, true);

                    chart.redraw();
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    },
   yAxis: [ {
        valueDecimals: 5,
        opposite: false,
        showRects: true,
        offset: 40,
        title: {
            text: 'Scale 1'
        }
    }, { valueDecimals: 5,
        opposite: true,
        showRects: true,
        offset: 90,
        title: {
            text: 'Scale 2'
        }
    }, { valueDecimals: 5,
        opposite: false,
        showRects: true,
        offset: 140,
        title: {
            text: 'Scale 3'
        }
    }],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    tooltip: {
                    xDateFormat: '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', // Shows only [Day, Mon dd, hh:mi:ss]
                    shared: true,
                    pointFormat: ' <span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.5f}</b>'+tooltipSuffix+' <br/>',
//                    valueDecimals: 5,
//                    crosshairs: true
     } ,
    series: example_data
});

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Regards
Amit

Comment: Hello Folks - I been thoroughly checking and realise that this question has not been asked before, wondering if any HighChart expert is able to help?

Answer (score 2):

You could set max for `xAxis` and increase it (through [Axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update)) when adding new points.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6u8q9kgp/5/

Other option is to add new series with hidden null value point (with x equal to a  future date) that will only increase visible range for `xAxis`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6u8q9kgp/4/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The technique you have mentioned

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The technique you have mentioned seems to show only next few seconds. I was actually looking for a handle (navigator bar) that the user can drag towards right and can see future events. Say now is 18:00 running every second.The now user can use the Navigator handle (similar to Range Selector) that can allow him to move it right past the current time to say 18:02 or 18:05 or 18:10 etc. I will be plotting the future events as vertical lines on X axis. Is there a way that you can mix and merge your technique with HighStock instance creation to achieve the objective? Thanks

Comment: @AmitMonga Even Highstock's navigator doesn't allow panning into not set xAxis range - you would have to define that range first or call setExtremes for axis. You could add a button that will setExtremes to show xAxis with future dates. API for setExtremes - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will go through the details and try it out.